# What is thonny,desktop file in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, files, .desktop

I installed thonny for python idle in my Ubuntu After installation I found a file on my desktop as thonny.desktop and it was there even after a restart.
What was this file?.
can I delete this file without facing any issues further?

Comment: If you click on it, it should start the application Thonny. If you don't want it on your desktop, you can delete it. It won't delete the actual application.

Comment: `.desktop` files are simple text. Read it with `less` to see what it does